# When to use use Provide / Inject and when config.globalProperties

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently working on a small VueJs SPA and the first time with **VueJs 3**. In
the past you could add helpers, classes to the Vue instance simply by using
**prototype**. With VueJs 3 this possibility was abolished and replaced with two new
possibilities:

1. **provide / inject**
2. **config.globalProperties**

I personally
find variant 2 charming because it is easy and quick to implement. With variant
one, I don't really understand the concept. I wonder why you explicitly add the
inject in the child componente and why it doesn't happen automatically. However.

Are there different application scenarios for using 1 and 2? I only ask because I find it strange to add helper classes under config. So weird from the naming.

Answer (score 1):

With provide / inject you can pass data from a parent component to a deeper nested child component, without the use of prop drilling.

Using config.globalProperties would mean that the data is available in all the components, instead of just the components that require it.

Comment: Thanks! To me, this sounds like simple state management, where I import the store into the components where I need them. Or am I wrong?

Comment: The above examples can be used without the use of a store. But indeed, using a store would also allow you to use data across different components.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Does the use of provide / inject actually have an advantage over config.globalProperty? Maybe memory etc.  In my opinion, I found the old prototype solution good! So I will probably use config.prototype in the future. Although I find it strange to call a custom class under config.

Comment: In my view, it is more clean to only have the data available in the required scope and not in the entire application. I think generally you should try to avoid global scope.